# UWP - x:Bind and Binding - FlipView inside AdaptativeGridView - Use only x:Bind

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, binding, datatemplate

new to .NET ecosystem.

The following code is working fine following MVVM in a blank UWP app.

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP.Blank.Mvvm.App01.Views.PrincipalPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP.Blank.Mvvm.App01"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:md="using:UWP.Blank.Mvvm.App01.Models"
    xmlns:vm="using:UWP.Blank.Mvvm.App01.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    x:Name="ThisPrincipalPage">

    <Page.Resources>



        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipView_ItemTemplate" x:DataType="md:MyFlipViewItem">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageLocation}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate">
            <Grid
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">

                <FlipView Width="300" Height="300"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipView_ItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisPrincipalPage, Path=ViewModel.FlipViewData}"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <controls:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="AdapGridView1"
                                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.AdaptativeGridViewData}"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate}"/>


    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Which looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYEyU.png)

The code behind is:

```
    public sealed partial class PrincipalPage : Page
    {

        // Reference to our view model.
        public PrincipalViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }



        public PrincipalPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new PrincipalViewModel();
        }


    }
```

And the ViewModel is an instance of this class:

```
    public class PrincipalViewModel
    {


        public ObservableCollection<int> AdaptativeGridViewData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        public ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem> FlipViewData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem>();

...

}
```

that provides two lists, one for the AdaptativeGridView control, and another for all the FlipViews inside of it.

**My question is, is there any way I can use x:Bind only?** Basically, because it claims to be faster. In case it is not possible, x:Bind is not a substitute of Binding, and makes everything even more confusing.

I tried two basic "intuitive options" which don't work.

**Option 1**, where ItemsSource property of the FlipView is changed to use x:Bind. Error claims:

*Invalid binding path 'ViewModel.FlipViewData' : Property 'ViewModel' not found on type 'DataTemplate'.*

Seems FlipView's DataTemplate has a DataContext different than expected. Maybe the DataContext is pointing to ViewModel.AdaptativeGridViewData, but, who knows? It is XAML. This is one of the reasons I am finding XAML an inconvenient since it behaves like a "black box". You know how to do something or you are in trouble.

In this case I tried to use classic Binding with "FindAncestor" utility to point back to ViewModel. In UWP however, AncestorType is not implemented.

(i.e., alike --> ItemsSource="{Binding FlipViewData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type AdaptativeGridView}}}" )

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate">
            <Grid
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">

                <FlipView Width="300" Height="300"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipView_ItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.FlipViewData}"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I am curious since I am not explicitely setting the x:DataType in the DataTemplate. So, why the DataContext is not the same as the AdaptativeGridView or any "normal" control in the Page?

**Option 2**, which explicitely sets x:DataType of the DataTemplate (note this is indeed working in the other DataTemplate "FlipView_ItemTemplate"). However, for the "AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate", there is a runtime error.

*Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in UWP.Blank.Mvvm.App01.exe*

and no more clues.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:PrincipalViewModel">
            <Grid
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">

                <FlipView Width="300" Height="300"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipView_ItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind FlipViewData}"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Any experience or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your DataType must match the type that the DataTemplate is displaying, in this case being INT for AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate. The DataContext of an ItemTemplate is of the individual item being displayed by that template, not the DataContext of the parent / ItemsControl. This behaviour is expected everywhere where a control inflates/create instances of the DataTemplate for you.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Thank you for sharing your comments! Related to your comment: So a DataTemplate cannot have an arbitrary type but must much the type of the elements of the "collection behind" (set in ItemsSource). If that is the case, why there exists a property x:DataType to configure?

Comment: x:DataType enables you to use x:Bind inside a DataTemplate (by allowing the compiler to  know what the target type is, thereby allowing it to generate the correct code-behind), otherwise you can only use traditional Binding. Most properties beginning with x: usually trigger special compiler logic, including the common x:Name (which creates the code that allows you to access named XAML elements from codebehind)

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Thank you for the comment. So, that would answer why Option 1 is not working since there is no x:DataType specified. Still, this does not explain why using x:DataType in the DataTemplate (and x:Bind internally) generetes a runtime error.

Comment: This is because you've specified a type that doesn't match the type you are binding too. The codebehind generated for X:Bind will try to cast the item being displayed in your DataTemplate as the type specified in X:DataType. In your case, it will be trying to cast an int as PrincipalViewModel, which will throw the InvalidCastException you see. (Unlike Binding which is dynamic and uses reflection to access objects, X:Bind creates code at compile time to manually sync properties, without reflection, so it needs to know the exact types to perform correct casts)

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Thank you for the explanation! I understand the point. So, with current structure there is no way to use x:Bind in the FlipView ¿?

Comment: With the current structure, no. But unless you have 10s/100s of these things active and updating properties at a time, the performance difference between Binding/x:Bind will be the least of your performance concerns. The cost of having a FlipView as a GridViewItem already costs so much more perf in comparison, so there's not too much need to worry about it here.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlakeThank you for the answer! Yeah, the main reason is not performance but elegance and using the "new" style as Microsoft states.